# how to check user authority level in login form VB.NET/MYSQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

FYI, I have tables Authority and Users. In my Users table, it has 4 columns namely: user_id, username, password, authority_id and in Authority table, it has 2 columns: authority_id, authority_level.

My login form asks user for their username and password. Upon giving the correct parameters, it should validate the user if it is an admin = 1, nurse = 2, or doctor = 2.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter UserName and Password Moron")
    Else
        'SQL Query To Get The Details
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlquerry = "Select * From users where username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' And password= '" + txtPassword.Text + "'"
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand()
        myCommand.Connection = SQLConnection
        myCommand.CommandText = sqlquerry
        'Starting The Query
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
        mydata = myCommand.ExecuteReader
        'To check the Username and password and to validate the login a
        If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Login")
        Else
            MsgBox("Welcome " + txtUsername.Text + "!")
            If authority Then
                frmMain.Show()
            Else
                frmMainNurse.Show()
            End If
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Notice that I haven't added something in this line:

```
If authority Then
```

I don't know how to do it in vb.net. So if anyone knows how to do this, I'll greatly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your else part

```
Else
    Dim authorityid = 0
    While mydata.Read()
        authorityid = mydata.GetInt32("authority_id")   
    End While
    MsgBox("Welcome " + txtUsername.Text + "!")
    If authorityid = 1 Then
       frmMain.Show()
    Else
       frmMainNurse.Show()
    End If
    Me.Hide()
End If
```

Comment: Hi may I ask, where do you get reader.GetInt32? What's that for? Thanks

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes- my bad, i updated my answer to correct variable name.